# Why don't buttons have the same baseline in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Here is my XML file

```
<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Butto1111111111111111111n" />

    <Button
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Butt1111111111111111on" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Bu111111111111111111tton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Style Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">128dp</item>
</style>
```

Here you can see that Buttons don't have the same baseline, how do I fix this?
[image]

Comment: The Above code is working fine for more me [check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7OyA.png)

Comment: `android:gravity="center_vertical"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a constraint layout will help fix your problem, in addition it will help you flatten your layout hierarchies.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:text="Butto1111111111111111111n"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:text="Butto1111111111111111111n"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:text="Butto1111111111111111111n"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your LinearLayout:

```
android:gravity="center_vertical"
```

to align the buttons

Comment: it didn't help(

Comment: What do you mean? I reproduced your code and the buttons are aligned perfectly.

Comment: buttons were just centered vertically in the layout but their baslines didn't change

Comment: Since all the buttons have the same height 128dp and they're all centered vetically how can their baselines not align?

Comment: I tried your answer one more time and now it worked, I don't know maybe it's some kind of random android magic

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the alignment of your layout :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Butto1111111111111111111n" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Butt1111111111111111on" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.SoundboardUnlockedButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Bu111111111111111111tton" />
</LinearLayout>
```